# NVDA screen reader requests wrong QAccessible::InterfaceType

Tags: c++, qt, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

I'm on Qt 5.9.1.

I'm trying to make an application accessible through screen readers. I have a custom widget (let's call it `MyWidget`) that contains text (a *lot* of it.) The text is drawn using `QPainter`, which is why a custom widget is used rather than something like `QTextBrowser`.

I implemented the `QAccessibleTextInterface` for the widget in a `AccessibleMyWidget` class that derives from `QAccessibleWidget` and `QAccessibleTextInterface`. It works fine with Orca under Linux, but when used in Windows 7 with NVDA, `QAccessibleInterface::interface_cast()` requests the wrong interface type. With Orca, I get requests for a `QAccessible::TextInterface`. In NVDA, it's always `QAccessible::ValueInterface`.

`AccessibleMyWidget` is defined as:

```
class AccessibleMyWidget:
    public QAccessibleWidget, public QAccessibleTextInterface {

public:
    explicit AccessibleMyWidget(QWidget* w)
        : QAccessibleWidget(w, QAccessible::EditableText)
    {
        Q_ASSERT(isValid());
    }

    void* interface_cast(QAccessible::InterfaceType t) override
    {
        if (t == QAccessible::TextInterface) {
            // !!! This is never requested with NVDA !!!
            return static_cast<QAccessibleTextInterface*>(this);
        }
        return QAccessibleWidget::interface_cast(t);
    }

    /*
     * QAccessibleTextInterface implementation below this point.
     */
    void addSelection(int startOffset, int endOffset) override;
    QString attributes(int offset, int* startOffset,
                       int* endOffset) const override;
    // etc.
};
```

With Orca under Linux, everything seems to work as intended. I get calls to `interface_cast()` for a `TextInterface`, and after that, the various functions of `QAccessibleTextInterface` are called. With NVDA under Linux, I just get `interface_cast()` calls for `ValueInterface`, and none of the `QAccessibleTextInterface` functions are called. Which means `MyWidget` is completely inaccessible, unless I override `QAccessibleWidget::text()` and just return all text as a single string, which means no cursor navigation, no selection support... It basically becomes just a `QLabel` at this point, but with a ton of text and thus very hard to use.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, an NVDA developer helped me track down the issue. It's because the MinGW version of Qt has IAccessible2 disabled and uses MSAA (Microsoft Active Accessibility) instead, which doesn't support any of these interfaces. IA2 needs COM, and MinGW doesn't support that.

So I would have to switch from GCC/MinGW to MSVC to make this work on Windows. Too bad that's not actually an option in the foreseeable future :-/

2020 update:
This has been fixed since. Not sure when exactly, but the current mingw Qt builds now support this.

Comment: Is that "Mingw" a reference to the **[original 32Bit only project](http://mingw.org/)** from *Software in the Public interest* or the **fork** that is **[Mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php)** that does work with Qt and supports both 32 and 64 bit Windows?

Comment: @SlySven It's mingw-w64. However, in 2017, the mingw builds of Qt had COM disabled. This has been fixed since though. I'll update the answer.

Comment: So, do you mean: in 2017 Qt was using "Mingw" and that had the COM interface disabled but since then they've switched to "Mingw-w64" OR that they were using "Mingw-w64" even back in 2017 but they had COM disabled then but it is not now?

Comment: @SlySven I mean it was using mingw-w64, but Qt only enabled the COM stuff in the msvc builds. Now they enable it for mingw as well. (And when people say "mingw" these days, they really mean "mingw-w64".)